# Balancing Parenthesis for Lab Project

Tags: java, stack, parentheses

```java
import stack.RStack;

public class Expressions {
    private RStack data;

    public Expressions() {
    }

    public boolean checkbalance(String expression) {
        char charAt;
        int i, len;
        len = expression.length();
        for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            charAt = expression.charAt(i);
            if(charAt == '(')
                push(charAt);
            else if(ch == ')') {
                if(isEmpty())
                    return false;
                else if((char)peek() == '(')
                    pop();
                else
                    return false;
            }
        }
        if(isEmpty())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public int precedence(char c) {
        if((c == '*') || (c == '/'))
            return 2;
        else if((c == '+') || (c == '-'))
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public boolean isOperand(char c) {
        if((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= '0' && c <= '9'))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public String infixToPostfix(String infix) {
        char c;
        int len, i;
        String postfix = "";
        len = infix.length();
        for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            c = infix.charAt(i);
            if(isOperand(c))
                postfix = postfix + c;
            else if(c == '(')
                push(c);
            else if(c == ')') {
                while((char)peek() != '(')
                    postfix = postfix + pop();
                pop();
            } else {
                while(!isEmpty() && (precedence(c) <= precedence((char)peek())))
                    postfix = postfix + pop();
                push(c);
            }
        }
        while(!isEmpty())
            postfix = postfix + pop();
        return postfix;
    }

    public RStack getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(RStack data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Any idea on why do i always  get "The method push(char) is undefined for the type Expressions", "the method peek() is undefined for the type Expressions", "The method isEmpty() is undefined for the type Expressions" and "The method pop() is undefined for the type Expressions"? when im trying to balance parenthesis for lab project and I always run into this issue

Comment: Because you have not defined those methods in your `Expressions` class.  Perhaps you intended to invoke them on the `RStack` reference?

Comment: I fixed your formatting of code this time. Before you post again, study the Help pages to learn about such matters.

Answer (score 0):

Your calls to `push` and `pop` do not exist. Therefore, the compiler complains.

If you meant to call those methods on your own class `Expressions`, you’ll need to define such methods. Do like you did with defining `precedence` and `isOperand`. See [The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) by Oracle.

If you meant to call those methods on an instance of another class, such as your mysterious `RStack` class, then you will need a reference to such an instance before you can call the methods. See [The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objects.html).

---

By the way, the `char` type has been essentially broken since Java 2, and legacy since Java 5. As a 16-bit value, `char` is physically incapable of representing most characters.

To work with individual characters, use [code point](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers. You’ll find various `codePoint` methods on classes such as `String`, `StringBuilder`, and `Character`.